# How to get spesific parts from a text? Python

Tags: python

I have a string like this.

```
'hsa:578\tup:Q16611\nhsa:578\tup:A0A0S2Z391\nhsa:9373\tup:Q9Y263\nhsa:9344\tup:Q9UL54\nhsa:5894\tup:P04049\nhsa:5894\tup:L7RRS6\nhsa:673\tup:P15056\n'
```

I want to get only values begin with "up:".
Like this:

- up:A0A0S2Z391
- up:Q9Y263
- up:Q9UL54.

How can i do that with python?

Comment: Using [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

Comment: Why did you add the tag for BASIC if your question is about Python? You know that BASIC is the name of a language, right?

Comment: Thank you. I have changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using re module for regular expressions.

```
import re

text = ''''hsa:578\tup:Q16611\nhsa:578\tup:A0A0S2Z391\nhsa:9373\tup:Q9Y263\nhsa:9344\tup:Q9UL54\nhsa:5894\tup:P04049\nhsa:5894\tup:L7RRS6\nhsa:673\tup:P15056\n'''
pattern = r'up:.*'
values = re.findall(pattern, text)
print(values)
```

Output:

```
['up:Q16611', 'up:A0A0S2Z391', 'up:Q9Y263', 'up:Q9UL54', 'up:P04049', 'up:L7RRS6', 'up:P15056']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the split() method for that.

Here is a link to the documentation:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?#str.split

Something like this could work for the string you posted:

```
s = 'hsa:578\tup:Q16611\nhsa:578\tup:A0A0S2Z391\nhsa:9373\tup:Q9Y263\nhsa:9344\tup:Q9UL54\nhsa:5894\tup:P04049\nhsa:5894\tup:L7RRS6\nhsa:673\tup:P15056\n'
res = []
for i in s.split('up')[1:]:
    res.append('up' + i.split()[0])
print(res)
```

output:

```
['up:Q16611', 'up:A0A0S2Z391', 'up:Q9Y263', 'up:Q9UL54', 'up:P04049', 'up:L7RRS6', 'up:P15056']
```